# How to prevent a javascript function from evaluating an argument assigned to a string variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax, console.log

Edited for clarification:

```
function Num(str) { 
  return str;
}
```

which returns when the input is 2^15

> 13

I want to know how I can keep it from evaluating str and just return 2^15 instead of returning 13.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You assign the string literal `"string"` to a variable. You console.log that variable. The output is the value of that string literal. What's unexpected about that? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = "2^15"; // wrap in double quotes to treat it as a string
```

As a sidenote, avoid calling your variables 'string', since it is a reserved keyword in a lot of languages and reduces readability.